# Failed to build with plugin from URL

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

**Decription:**
After installing the latest head version of *cordova-plugin-background-mode*, build for Android fails. However, if I run the build command without first deleting node_modules, platforms and plugins, the build works just fine.

In config.xml: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git" />`

In package.json: `"dependencies": {
"cordova-plugin-background-mode": "git+https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git"
}`

In package-lock.json: `"cordova-plugin-background-mode": { 
"version": "git+https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git#a2352f5d8b17de5799b35177d9c7c4f32f66c49e"`

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git
2. delete node_modules, platforms and plugins (as if I want to simulate a fresh restore)
3. ionic cordova build android

**Output:**

```
Looks like a fresh checkout! No ./node_modules directory found. Would you like to install project dependencies? Yes
Installing dependencies may take several minutes!
> npm i
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1):

        npm ERR! code 128
        npm ERR! Command failed: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE submodule update -q --init --recursive
        npm ERR! fatal: 'submodule' appears to be a git command, but we were not
        npm ERR! able to execute it. Maybe git-submodule is broken?
        npm ERR!
```

**Ionic info:**
cli packages: (C:\Users\a\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.3
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this npm issue:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20815

Comment: I've already tried to reinstall it. My version of `git` is now 2.19.1 (https://git-scm.com/) and, except for this cordova/ionic issue, everything seems to work fine

Comment: I found this to be an unresolved issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2716